# Face Detection with OpenCV for non frontal images

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I am trying to use opencv to detect faces. Faces are not frontal, the camera captured the faces from side so only one eye and part of the mouth is viewed. I tried HaarDetectObjects with multiple configurations without getting benefit. I changed the cascade and I tested:
haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml, haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml,haarcascade_profileface.xml with very bad results. Are there any other better cascades? Are there other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Now you have in OpenCV the new LBP cascade for profile faces, created by Vadim Pisarevsky:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml

Apparently, it only detects right profile faces, so to detect all profile faces one has to run a second step with the image flipped.

Comment: This works great for full-profile faces. However doesn't always work great for partially profile faces. Are there better version of a profile cascade available by now?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can always train your own set of faces using a database of profile faces (you should be able to find some databases of faces around). If you do so, please submit the generated cascade to OpenCV so that it is available to the community.

Comment: That is interesting. Thanks for documenting this limitation and the procedure to make it work with all profile faces.

Answer (score 10):

The cascade files you referenced (e.g. aarcascade_frontalface_default.xml, haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml, haarcascade_profileface.xml) are created using full frontal faces to *detect* full frontal faces. So, half of a face wouldn't obviously be correctly recognized as the correct shape to a computer.

What you may need to do in this situation is to train OpenCV to recognize your object of interest which is "half of a face_ in this case. In OpenCV jargon it is known as - '[HaarTraining](https://code.google.com/p/tutorial-haartraining/)'. Use [this](https://code.google.com/p/tutorial-haartraining/), [this](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs4411/wiki/index.php?title=OpenCV_Guide) and [this](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) article as a starting point to start training.

Once you have trained OpenCV using your data (e.g. lots of different images of half of a face), you will have an XML cascade file ready which you can plug into your own code to detect half of a face.

Good luck!

Comment: Haarcascade_profileface.xml is for profile faces(Non-frontal, but sideways)

Comment: By the way, tried the Haarcascade profile face xml, but turns out its not very accurate.

Comment: @gsbabil, the second link is broken and that tutorial is quite high level and written by a non-native speaker of English which makes it more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I had been dealing with the same problem of face detection for non-frontal images. Try using Multi Task CNN. It's the best solution for face detection and alignment. It is able to deal with problems like various poses, lighting, occlusion.

The paper is available at [Link](https://kpzhang93.github.io/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment/index.html). The code is available on GitHub at [Link](https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment). I used the python implementation and the results are outstanding. Although the code is a little slow if the image has a lot of faces.

Although if you want to stick to OpenCV, then a new deep learning model for face detection has been added to OpenCV. The results are not as good as Multi Task CNN. There's an implementation of OpenCV Deep Learning Model for Face Detection at pyimagesearch [Link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/)

Comment: did you use the matlab version you linked to or the highly recommended C++ and Caffe version?

Comment: actually I am not sure how to get a free version of matlab beyond the trial.

Comment: No, I did not use the Matlab or C++ version. Universities generally provide free Matlab to students or you can try GNU Octave

Comment: `The results are not as good as Multi Task CNN` I am testing both mtcnn face detection and deep learning face detection and to me both looks perfect. Why do you think MTCNN is much better than deep learning opencv face detection.?